# How do I run Node Js on my VPS server

Tags: node.js

I write my server file with node.js and has successfully test in my local , i install node.js and mongoDB plugin on my server , that is windows, but when i type server url instead of my ip in my android app I can't find server and get error server not found
Please help me

Comment: What is the exact URL you are typing in the browser?  What is the exact error you get in the browser?  And, have you properly configured DNS so your domain points to your server?

Comment: my URL for example is x.x.x.x/login that x.x.x.x is a valid ip of my server and login name is one of my server files.error is not found x.x.x.x/login.I don't know!I just set the URL address in my android app

Comment: Is x.x.x.x a "public" IP address of your server that is available from the general internet?

Comment: Yes, this replay to ping.I install node js and robo mongo and mongoDB on server,need to do something else?

Comment: Do you have a nodejs route handler for your particular url?  Nodejs does not serve any files by default.

Comment: no I have not.how do i set it handler?

Comment: You will have to include the relevant part of your node server code in your question.